# combination of pairs of columns BUT not rows in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

How to calculate the combinations of pairs of columns in a data frame, but restrict it, so that it does not considers combinations among rows?

I have a data frame like the following, where each column is a variable.

```
ID A B C D E F G H I J
1   12  185 NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
2   35  20  11  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
3   45  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

I want an output like this:

```
    Var1 
 12, 185
 35, 20
 35, 11
 20, 11
 45, 45
```

I tried the following code, but it considers ALL possible pairs of combinations among columns and rows. I want each row to be consider independently from each other. Does someone have an idea? Thanks.

```
numNetList <- read.csv2("abd.csv", sep=";")

comb <- lapply(numNetList, function(x) if (length(x) > 1) 
  combn(sort(as.numeric(x)), 2))
combb <- do.call(cbind, comb)

pajek_list <- as.data.frame(table(paste(combb[1,], combb[2,], sep = ',')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not the efficient method, but solves the problem

```
func <- function(x){
  t = as.character(x[!is.na(x)])
  if (length(t)==1) 
  t = rep(t,2)
  t1 = combn(t,2)
}

l = apply(df[-1], 1, func)
l1 <- as.data.frame(l)
colnames(l1) = NULL
l2= data.frame(t(l1))

library(tidyr)
unite(l2, "new_col", X1,X2 ,sep = ",")

#   new_col
#    12,185
#    35,20
#    35,11
#    20,11
#    45,45
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a combination of `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tibble(A = c(12,35,45), B = c(185, 20, NA), C = c(NA, 11, NA))

df %>% 
  mutate(group = 1:n()) %>% 
  gather(col, val, -group) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  expand(col, val) %>%  
  distinct(val) %>% 
  summarise(val = toString(val))
```